# Como fazer cURL entre containers?

Tags: php, docker

*Comecei a utilizar Docker a pouco tempo, provavelmente por isso fiquei preso nesse problema.*

Tenho uma **API** e um **Front** que fica fazendo requisições via **cURL** para ela.

Porém quando coloquei esses projetos no Docker e separei eles em **containers** (para "simular" a situação real, já que a **API** e o **Front** ficam em servidores separados) as requisições **cURL** pararam de funcionar.

Fiz outros testes e não consegui fazer o **cURL** funcionar entre **containers**. Segue imagem de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Imagem Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/o2multi/apache-php7/) usada para criar os dois containers.
No teste acima foi usado o seguinte Docker-compose (como exemplificado na próxima imagem a única diferença entre os dois containers e o docker-compose é a porta e os nomes dos containers):

```
a:
environment:
    TZ: "America/Sao_Paulo"
image: o2multi/apache-php7
ports:
    - "80:80"
volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html/
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tento fazer cURL para outros lugares ele funciona perfeitamente.
Como faço para ele funcionar entre os containers?

Tentativas efetuadas ----------------

```
version: '2' 
services:
a:
    environment:
        TZ: "America/Sao_Paulo"
    image: o2multi/apache-php7
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./a:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - b
b:
    environment:
        TZ: "America/Sao_Paulo"
    image: o2multi/apache-php7
    ports:
        - "443:80"
    volumes:
        - ./b:/var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui chegar a seguinte solução:

- Você deve linkar os containers no docker-compose

  - Usando o **links**: *nome_container* se for subir os containers no mesmo docker-compose.
  - Usando **external_links**: *nome_container* para linkar seu container a um outro container que já esta ativo.
- Verificar o **IP** do container que vai receber as requisições.
- Usar o **IP** no **cURL** ao invés do endereço `http://localhost:porta` do container

Segue o docker-compose usado:

```
version: '2'                                                        
services:
a:
    environment:
        TZ: "America/Sao_Paulo"
    image: o2multi/apache-php7
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./a:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - b
b:
    image: o2multi/apache-php7
    ports:
        - "443:80"
    volumes:
        - ./b:/var/www/html/
```

Em seguida usei o comando **docker insect *nome_container*** e procurei o **IP**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso no cURL somente troquei a url **`http://localhost:443`** por **`http://172.17.0.5`** e o cURL passou a funcionar perfeitamente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar utilizar o link, o seu Docker-compose só tem um container definido, vou colocar um exemplo de uma conexão com banco de dados para você ter uma ideia:

```
version: '2'

services:
  server-front:
    image: sua/imagem
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    build:
      context: ./pasta-do-front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - server-back

  server-back:
    image: sua/imagem
    ports:
      - "porta:porta"
    volumes:
      - ./seu-volume
    build:
      context: ./pasta-do-back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Veja que o front tem um link com o back, você chamaria o servidor pelo link `http://server-back:porta` dentro do seu container porque ele vai criar o host automaticamente.

Comment: Tinha subido os containers separados cada um com um docker-compose. Fiz o que você sugeriu, criei um docker-compose com os dois containers e usei o **links** para linkar o front com o back porém o erro persiste.
O link funcionou pois se tento fazer uma requisição do back para o front fica carregando muito tempo e da timeout, se faço do front para o back não retorna erro. Porém não retorna os dados também.

Comment: Você vai precisar expor suas portas no back e no front... Mas por que você está tentando fazer uma chamada no back para o front

Comment: Estava somente efetuando testes para verificar se link entre os containers tinha realmente funcionado. Expus as portas mas tbm não funcionou.